# calculating volume of cube

Tags: c, linux

```
 printf("The Volume of the cuboid with a height of%d", height);
 printf("and width of%d\n", width);
 printf("and depth of%d\n", depth);
 printf("Gives you the Volume of %lf\n", vcuboid);
```

"volumeofcuboid.c:5: error: âheightâ undeclared here (not in a function) volumeofcuboid.c:5: error: âwidthâ undeclared here (not in a function) volumeofcuboid.c:5: error: âdepthâ undeclared here (not in a function) "

Comment: You should probably compile it......

Comment: Putting `#!/bin/bash` at the start probably isn't helping any.

Comment: Oh man this is so wrong. `vcuboid=((height*width*depth));`  Nope.

Comment: gccvolumeofcuboid.c –o volumeofcuboid >>> ./volumeofcuboid ...... then its says file is in directory

Comment: @KevinDTimm I think this would crash the compiler, compilers can't fix stupid.

Comment: @ScottyBauer Oh yeah, it needs more parentheses, like `vcuboid = ((((((height*width*depth))))))`

Comment: I'm so glad people are trying to program yet they have absolutely no idea what they are even doing...

Comment: @ScottyBauer - it shouldn't crash it, but it would certainly make it bark!  Interestingly, without the 'prototype definition' of vcuboid, it would almost work.

Comment: If you run `gcc volumeofcuboid.c –o volumeofcuboid`, you will get error messages. This: `vcuboid (height,width,depth);` looks like an old-style function declaration. You want it to be a *variable* declaration, and it should be inside your `main` function.

Comment: volumeofcuboid.c:5: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
volumeofcuboid.c:5: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
volumeofcuboid.c: In function âmainâ:
volumeofcuboid.c:22: error: invalid lvalue in assignment

Comment: People tend to be a bit mean here when you post a question without working through the basics, but I can still remember what it feels like when you are a beginner.  Take away the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`) - that is shell script syntax, not C.  You need to use `gcc` to compile this into an executable which you can then run.  What you have is called C source code - you can't run it directly.  You have also declared `vcuboid` as a function, where it should instead be a `double` (but you could use an `int` instead).

Comment: thank you very much paddy.. as you said im a beginner ive been watching alot of tutorial videos i'll get there one day lol

Comment: @user2661944 Being a beginner is not an excuse for asking such a question. I do remember being a beginner - I **never ever** thought that one can run raw C source as a shell script. Seriously, I mean, don't be lazy! Try using your brain. Read up more on how C programming works. **Learn is *small* steps.** Don't try to do more than you can do at once, because that only leads to this kind of horribly bad questions and what's even worse, you'll be misled as to what the actual problem is and what you are doing.

Comment: @user2661944: In all seriousness, you need to get an actual book. C is not very forgiving, a "good attempt" won't even get you started as you're finding out, it won't even compile if your syntax isn't 100% correct. And remember, the errors that your compiler tells you about are the easy ones, it'll be hard to garner sympathy by posting code that won't even compile for reasons that your compiler is already shouting at you.

Comment: Thanks guys i will get a book. but your answers has been useful.

Answer (score 2):

For starters:

1. `#!/bin/bash`

C is not a shell script. Not even if you're using cshell.

1. `vcuboid (height,width,depth);`

Not a valid function prototype, and you never provide an actual function.

1. `main ()`

Not a valid definition of `main()`, should be `int main(void)`.

1. `vcuboid=((height*width*depth));`

`vcuboid` has not been defined.

And just, no.

1. `exit(0);`

`return 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Look at Paul Griffiths' answer to correct your code.
If it does not work, take this code to correct yours.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_volume(int h,int w,int d);

int main(void) {
  int height = 0, width = 0, depth = 0, volume;
  printf("Height : ");
  scanf("%d", &height);
  printf("Width : ");
  scanf("%d", &width);
  printf("Depth : ");
  scanf("%d", &depth);

  volume = get_volume(height,width,depth);

  printf("Volume : %d * %d * %d = %d\n", height, width, depth, volume);
  return 0;
}


int get_volume(int h,int w,int d) {
  return h * w * d;
}
```